# update SQl table from values in excel

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, excel, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using the SQL Developer or SQl express.

How do i get the values from an excel sheet and update those in a column of my database...

Please help thanks.

i have this and im running it but i get error:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
            'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\books.xls',
            'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

i get error now

OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Could not find installable ISAM.".

thanks

Comment: And what error might you be getting?

Comment: SQL Server blocked access to STATEMENT 'OpenRowset/OpenDatasource' of component 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server. A system administrator can enable the use of 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' by using sp_configure. For more information about enabling 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', see "Surface Area Configuration" in SQL Server Books Online.

Comment: Have you checked out the Surface Area Configuration tool as the error indicates?

Comment: the problem is i cannot find the Surface Area Configuration tool

Comment: See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187569.aspx

Comment: so the above error is solved but i get new error

Comment: OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Could not find installable ISAM.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THIS IS HOW MY CODE WORKS

```
INSERT INTO TEMPTABLE (name)
 SELECT * 
   FROM OPENROWSET(
                   'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
                   'Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO;DATABASE=C:\test.xls', 
                   'Select * from [Sheet1$]'
                  );
```

i hope this helps some1

Answer (score 1):

Do you have [SQL Server Management Studio Express?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365247.aspx) If so, try using the Import/Export Wizard to import the spreadsheet into a new  table.

Comment: but i cannot find import or expot wizard??

Comment: most probably ill be using SQL developer...please..if you kno a way for this it will be great...

Comment: Please see the link I posted, which will take you to the download for SQL Server Management Studio Express. This application includes an import/export wizard that will step you through import of an Excel file (among other formats).