# Update database table column values with new Excel column values

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have a table in the database.

```
id : Name : Category
--------------------
1  : jake : admin
```

I have used sqlbulkcopy for inserting new rows into the database table from an excel sheet containing two columns 'Name' and 'Category'.

Now, I have another requirement and that is updating the values of the column `Name` and `Category` from the same Excel sheet but with newly updated values. My question is, is this possible? I just need a way to update the values of the column. I went through this reference.

[update SQl table from values in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513256/update-sql-table-from-values-in-excel)

but I don't know how to implement it.

Any help or suggestion will be greatly appreciate.

Thanks.

The code for uploading and importing excel file using sqlbulkcopy is below.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/" + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName)));
        string file = Server.MapPath("~/"+Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName));
        string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Excel 8.0; Extended Properties=HDR=Yes;IMEX=1; Data Source=" + file + ";";

        using (OleDbConnection olecon = new OleDbConnection(constr))
        {
            OleDbCommand olecmd = new OleDbCommand("select Name, Category FROM [Sheet1$]", olecon);
            olecon.Open();

            using (DbDataReader dbrdr = olecmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                string sqlcon = "Data Source=matty2011-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mydb; Integrated Security=True";

                using (SqlBulkCopy sqlbulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlcon))
                {
                    sqlbulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(0, 1);
                    sqlbulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add(1, 2);
                    sqlbulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "exceldata";
                    sqlbulkcopy.WriteToServer(dbrdr);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("Please select a file for upload.!"); return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> hi
>
> if possible use SSIS to solve
>   Simply by DTS

note : SSIS DTS will append the existing data